# Bitmaps stretching when i turn to Landscape orientation

Tags: android, bitmap, landscape, stretch

I write application which uses both landscape and portrait orientation.
Some LinearLayouts have android:backround resources set like

```
...
android:background="@drawable/main_sep_tiled"
...
```

main_sep_tiled.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:src="@drawable/reticular_pattern" 
android:tileMode="repeat">
</bitmap>
```

It works fine when i watching it in portrait orientation mode. But when it goes to landscape, small **reticular_pattern**  image file stretches to full screen wigth, with no repeats. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout file in folder layout-land inside res folder.. in that file customise as you want to view the bitmap in landscape mode..

Answer (score 0):

set this two properties for ImageView that might help you

```
Scale Type = fitCenter
Adjust View Bounds = true
```

Comment: you don't want your answer? if your problem solved let others no, otherwise add comment on answers and reject.

Comment: No, i haven't solved this problem yet. Decided to postpone it until better times